# Sidebar marker list by category not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I make a map with google map api v3. I want to make sidebar that listed marker divided by categories. When marker list in the side bar is clicked, marker on the map will appear its info, like this example http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html. Here is map.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      #category_panel {
    background-color : white;
    padding : 5px;
    font-size : 13px;
    margin-top : 5px;
    border : 1px solid #aaa;
      }
      #map {
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    padding : 0;
    left : 3%;
    top : 10%;
      }
      #side_bar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 3%;
    left: 70%;
    border : 1px solid #aaa;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&amp;key=AIzaSyDKXwzDz8D96-bipZjRwkW97gcdHkOHt2M">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-6.9667, 110.41677),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);

var selectDiv = $("#category_panel")[0];
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(selectDiv);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("data.txt", function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(key, data) {

        var clusterer;

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        // Marker Clusterer setup
        var mcOptions = {
        gridSize : 1,
        maxZoom : 15
        };
    clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

    var markers = {};
    var side_bar_html = "";

    // Looping JSON data
    for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
        var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
            category = data.category;

        if (category in markers == false) {
            markers[category] = [];
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : latLng,
            title : data.title,
        });
        markers[category].push(marker);

//      document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
//      side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:(marker, data)(' + (markers.length-1) + ')">' + data.title + '<\/a><br><br>';

        (function (marker, data) {

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
            infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        })(marker, data);

    function makeSidebar() {
    //var html = "";
        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
        var data = json[i],
            latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
            category = data.category;

        if (category in markers == false) {
            markers[category] = [];
        }
            {
                side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:(marker, data)(' + i + ')">' + data.title + '<\/a><br>';
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
    }


    }// loop ends


    $("#category").change(function()
        {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        clusterer.clearMarkers();
        clusterer.addMarkers(markers[selected]);
        });
    $("#category").change();
    makeSidebar();


        });
    });
});
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div id="side_bar"></div> 

      <div lang="en" id="category_panel">
    Category:<select id="category">
      <option value="category1">category 1</option>
      <option value="category2">category 2</option>
    </select>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here is data.txt

```
[
    {
    "title": "1A",
    "lat": -6.984,
    "lng": 110.41,
    "description": "1B",
    "category": "category1"
    },
    {
    "title": "1B",
    "lat": -6.9963,
    "lng": 110.398,
    "description": "1B",
    "category": "category1"
    },
    {
    "title": "2A",
    "lat": -6.9904,
    "lng": 110.42307,
    "description": "2B",
    "category": "category2"
    },
    {
    "title": "2B",
    "lat": -7.003,
    "lng": 110.4247,
    "description": "2B",
    "category": "category2"
    }
]
```

The problem is: first, marker link in the side bar doesn't work when clicked.
Second, all of marker data always appear, it should be appeared when category is selected only.
Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? I can't find that question anymore so perhaps you deleted it.  Why would you expect this `'<a href="javascript:(marker, data)(' + i + ')">' + data.title + '<\/a><br>';` to do anything useful in the sidebar? It gives me a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: marker is not defined`

Comment: Yes I did. It's a little different code, I've been searching & trying to make the sidebar. I'm sorry I don't know what is the error, I don't see any error in my browser

Comment: Look in the javascript console after clicking on the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working example of what I *think* you want](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories_dropdown_JSON.html)

Started from the example referenced.

1. added getJSON (with a modified version of your JSON format)
2. added mycategoryclick function
3. changed checkbox functionality to select (dropdown)

   ```
   function createMarker(latlng,name,html,category) {
     var contentString = html;
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latlng,
       icon: getMarkerImage(category2color(category)), // gicons[category],
       map: map,
       title: name,
       zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
       });
       // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
       marker.mycategory = category;                                 
       marker.myname = name;
       gmarkers.push(marker);

     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
       infowindow.open(map,marker);
     });
     return marker;
   }

     function select(category) {
       for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
         if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == category) {
           gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
         } else {
           gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
         }
       }
       // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
       infowindow.close();
       // == rebuild the side bar
       makeSidebar();
     }

     function createCategoryDropdown(category) {
       var select_holder = document.getElementById('select_holder');
       var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.setAttribute("name",category);
       option.setAttribute("value",category);
       option.innerHTML = category;
       select_holder.appendChild(option);
     }


     function mycategoryclick(category,i) {
       google.maps.event.trigger(markers[category][i],"click");
     }

     // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
     function makeSidebar() {
       var html = "";
       for (category in markers) {
         // html += "<b>"+category+"</b><br>";
         for (var i=0; i<markers[category].length; i++) {
           if (markers[category][i].getVisible()) {
             html += '<a href="javascript:mycategoryclick(&quot;'+category+'&quot;,' + i + ')">' + markers[category][i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
           }
         }
       }
       document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
     }

   function initialize() {
     var myOptions = {
       zoom: 11,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.8363,-3.0377),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
       infowindow.close();
     });

   // Read the data
   $.getJSON("SO_20140622_data.txt", function(json) {
       var firstcat = null;
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
         // obtain the attribues of each marker
         var lat = parseFloat(json[i].lat);
         var lng = parseFloat(json[i].lng);
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
     bounds.extend(point);
         var name = json[i].title;
         var category = json[i].category;
         var html = "<b>"+name+"<\/b><p>"+json[i].description+"</p>category:"+category;
         // create the marker
         var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
         if (category in markers == false) {
       if (firstcat == null) firstcat = category;
           markers[category] = [];
         }
         markers[category].push(marker);
       }

       // == create the categories dropdowns ==
       for (category in markers) {
     createCategoryDropdown(category);
       }
       // == show the first category
       select(firstcat);

       // == create the initial sidebar ==
       makeSidebar();

       // == fit the viewport to _all_ the markers ==
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. You made it much more perfect